# What job analysis methods are these?

Tags: new-job, human-resources, job-description

Its my first business HR course. In an in-class question, our prof gave us this question and answered it in a way that didnt convince me:

> Review the following job analysis methods and then write the letter corresponding to each method before the situation in which it would be the most appropriate.
>
> A. Questionnaire
>
> B. Interview
>
> C. Diary
>
> D. Observation
>
> E. Subject matter expert panel
>
> 1. On your staff, you have an industrial engineer who is an efficiency expert. You want her to improve the productivity of your machinists.
> 2. You have a new job to analyze, and you would like to get help from a few other professionals who know the job much better than you do.
> 3. You have several service call employees who repair a variety of computers. You would like to have a better idea of what types of computers they are fixing.

My prof solved them as follows: A, E and B respectively. 
But I think the first is E, the second is B and the third is D.

What is the correct answer?

Comment: Did you ask your professor for rationale of their choice?

Comment: This seems highly subjective, I'm not sure there really is a one single right answer, just personal preference. You can argue that some are definitely not correct, but the rest then fall into grey areas.

Answer (score 4):

The "correct" answer is what your course (*professor*) says to be correct.<sup>*</sup>

In practice, most of these categories overlap and there is no straightforward one-to-one mapping. Based on the scenario, scope and circumstances, it might change - so there's no universally correct answer, only what's applicable in a current setting.

In case you feel you have a difference in opinion with your professor, the best thing to exercise is to ask a question to your professor as why their conclusion is correct, over your choice of answers.

---

*[*] - The target of the course is most likely to make you aware of different scenarios, and the answers might be based on certain conditions. They don't necessarily guarantee universal applicability.*

Answer (score 1):

Ask your professor to explain. That's her job.

Some practical questions for you to consider:

- Why? Always why? Why does the HR professional need the information, who will use it, and what for?
- Where can an HR professional get a useful questionnaire to give to an industrial engineer? What kind of survey questions would be useful?
- Does the company have the custom of gathering subject-matter-expert panels? Or would that be too formal? Could you do some research, write a draft of a job description, and ask a subject-matter expert or the hiring manager to help you make it good?
- Why not ask the manager of the field-service techs if they keep track of what kind of machines they service?